# Word request - What is the word to describe a line or sentence that you can sing

Tags: word-request

I wonder if there is any words in English to describe a line which you can sing.

The line (or sentence) doesn't come from a song. So for example, saying "a line from a song" is not correct.

Comment: Try *lyric*: "She sang the lyric in a beautiful contralto voice."

Comment: You can also call a sentence that sounds like something that you can sing a *lyrical sentence.*

Comment: There isn't a specific word for this. Lyric is used to mean "a line from a song". I don't think there is a specific word for "A line you can sing, but isn't from a song", so you would have to simply describe it as "lyrical" or something like that.

Comment: The main meaning **lyrical** has nothing to do with singing. The second meaning comes close, but it is not appropriate as an answer for this question **Relating to the words of a popular song.** https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lyrical

Comment: What's your criteria for "you can sing"?  Because I can sing just about anything written down - even though it may sound terrible.

Comment: Not sure there is such a word since pretty much anything can be sung.  "They got! The mustard! Ouuuuuuut"  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VCO0J1N661U

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

- *Lyrical* or *poetical* to suggest that the words could be lyrics
- *Singable* to suggest it could be sung
- *Rhythmic* to suggest the words had a pattern, or rhythm that would lend itself to song

Answer (score 0):

You can call it "**a singable line/phrase/sentence**"